# Transitivity analysis of subjunctives and imperatives

Tags: modality, transitivity, imperative, systemic-functional, subjunctive

I'm attempting a functional analysis of the text of the Catholic Mass, primarily in English but with reference to the Latin. The use of grammatical moods is quite rich, with plenty of subjunctives ('God bless you'), imperatives ('Go in peace') and cohortatives ('Let us pray'; imperative in English, subjunctive in Latin). The interpersonal metafunction is my first stop here: taking as boulomaic modality the English subjunctives, and as deontic the imperatives and cohortatives. I'm having trouble, though, examining the transitivity of these sentences. Do they *translate* them into the indicative mood, so that the transitivity of 'God bless you' is identical to 'God blesses you', 'Go in peace' as 'You go in peace', or 'Let us pray' as 'We pray' or even 'We let ourselves pray'? This last thought is where I felt I needed some advice. Any thoughts or comments would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The recent revision of the English Mass liturgy brings the English much closer to the Latin than it has been. Many of the same constructions show up in the Latin and English, which was not the case before.

Comment: @jlawler Thank you for your comment. I am looking at the change from the translation based on dynamic equivalence to one that is more literal. The choices made are interesting, and the dynamic equivalence does hold up under scrutiny. A lot of what has been said about the change in translation is quite emotive.

Comment: I grew up Catholic in the mid 1950s and was an altar boy, so of course I memorized a great deal of the Latin. When the first English translation came out, I was very disappointed because it was so different from the Latin I knew that is sounded very silly, somehow. The newer version is far more satisfying. Though I still prefer the Latin.

Comment: (I'm not sure whether people will consider this on-topic here, but if it ends up closed, I'd recommend re-asking on Latin.SE.)

Comment: @Draconis my question is not really one of Latin but of systemic- functional grammar.

Comment: I will note for potential answerers that the term (and tag) "transitivity" is overloaded, and means something a bit different in systemic-functional grammar than one might expect from its use in other linguistic disciplines.

Comment: Exactly. There are many theories of transitivity; for that reason I prefer to use it as applied only to clauses, not particular verbs. One can usually determine whether a given English clause is transitive or intransitive, but very few verbs are intrinsically one or the other syntactically. Every verb is different.